# Fancy chapter in french

Tags: languages

[image]I use fancy chapters. However, it is written "chapitre" instead of "chapter" (see last code line) and I dont understand why.
Could you help me? thanks

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
% Font style definition

% Interline setting
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\blap}[1]{\vbox to 0pt{#1\vss}}
\newcommand\AtUpperLeftCorner[3]{%
  \put(\LenToUnit{#1},\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperheight-#2}){\blap{#3}}%
}
\newcommand\AtTopCenterPage[2]{%
  \put(\LenToUnit{.5\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperheight-#1}){\blap{\hbox to 0pt{\hss#2\hss}}}%
}
\newcommand\AtUpperRightCorner[3]{%
  \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-#1},\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperheight-#2}){\blap{\llap{#3}}}%
}

\title{\huge{Development and characterization of a gradient structured material elaborated by direct deposition additive manufacturing}}
\author{\textsc{Corongiu} Chiara}
\date{\today}
\makeatletter
 \geometry{hmargin=2cm,vmargin=3cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \AddToShipoutPicture{
        \AtUpperLeftCorner{1.5cm}{1.8cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{pgarde/uliege.jpg}}
       % \AtTopCenterPage{1.5cm}{1cm}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{pgarde/mms_logo.png}}
        \AtUpperRightCorner{1.5cm}{0.6cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{pgarde/Sonaca2.png}}
    }

    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{5cm}
        \HRule
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \textsc{\textbf{\@title}}
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \HRule
        \vspace*{0.5cm}
        \LARGE{\textit{Master thesis submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements\\
for the degree of Master in Aerospace Engineering by\\ \vspace{0.2cm}} \@author}\\
    \end{center}
\vfill
\begin{center}
 \large{University of Liège - Faculty of Applied Sciences\\
Academic year 2019-2020}   
\end{center}



  %  \begin{center}
  %      \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{data/footer.jpg}}
 %   \end{center}

\end{titlepage}
\ClearShipoutPicture
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\english
\chapter*{Abstract}
\newpage
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter*{Introduction}

\chapter{Powder characterisation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with this code. Also, where is defined `\english`, line 67? Isee what it means, but this supposes you defined it somewhere, in tne context of  babel using two languages (of which one is, presumably, French).

Comment: no I dont, it was another thing I tried to have chapter written in english

Answer (score 0):

Your document cannot be compiled, because it has an unknown command (`\english`) and because it uses images that we don't have access to.

Anyway, replace

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

with

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

and you will get “Chapitre” instead of “Chapter”.

If you want to write the whole document in English but you still want to have “Chapitre” instead of “Chapter”, then keep the

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

line and add

```
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\chaptername}%
    {Chapitre}%
}
```

to the preamble of your document.

Comment: thanks for answering but the problem is I want "chapter" instead of "chapitre". I dont understand why it is in french I never asked for it

Comment: What are you talking about? If I comment the lines that mention images that I don't have access to and if I also comment the line which consists of the `\english` command, then I get to compile your document and I get “Chapter”, not “Chapitre”. What do you get if you do the same thing?

Comment: I just add a picture to my initial post to show you. Its very strange

Comment: And what do you get if you compile **the exact same file** that you posted in your question?